# Is there a name for the following discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, terminology

In working in a probability application, I came upon a discrete random variable with support on $\mathbb N$ having p.m.f. $$\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac1n\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}(1-p)^{n-1}p^n.$$ Here $p\in(0,1)$. I was wondering if this belongs to some parametric family, and if so, what is the name for that family?

Comment: This issue involving Catalan numbers is well treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487019/305862). See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/586007/147896) as well

Comment: Thank you, those references are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Some people call it Sibuya distribution.

Comment: This is thin enough at the moment that it could probably be a comment. It would be helpful to provide a source for this terminology.

Comment: I cannot find a Sibuya or Sibuya like distribution in the literature that seems to have the form as in my question. Do you have any reference?

Comment: Indeed, in this [document](https://koara.lib.keio.ac.jp/xoonips/modules/xoonips/download.php/KO50001004-00340001-0001.pdf?file_id=96707)  by Sibuya himself, I don't find anything that is like the distribution in question.